# Chrome Cross-Domain PATCH request not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-domain

I have a website with REST Api and now I´m creating a browser extension, which will collect data from some pages and send them back to the REST Api. Because I want my extension to be compatible with both firefox and chrome, and to be easily maintainable, I´m injecting the actual code into page as a script tag, which is then executed like normal javascript.
I´m currently working only on chrome version of the extension and I´ve run into a problem:

When I´m trying to send my data to the api (PATCH request), chrome won´t let me saying:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://my.rest/api. Origin http://website.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I have the Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Methods and Origin all set to proper values, but it still doesn´t work. It works with GET requests though. I´ve also tried POST and PUT request but those don´t work either.

Here are my headers:

Request:

```
OPTIONS /some/api/path HTTP/1.1
Host: my.rest
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: PATCH
Origin: http://website.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
X-FireLogger: 1.1
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, x-http-auth-user, x-http-auth-token, origin, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://website.com/index.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: cs-CZ,cs;q=0.8
```

Response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, x-http-auth-user, x-http-auth-token, origin, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 04 Jul 2013 10:50:08 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) PHP/5.4.3
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By:Nette Framework
```

I´ve also tried setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to exactly same value as Origin header, but it didn´t work. Furthemore it seems to be working in Firefox. I have Chrome 27, which should be up-to-date.

Comment: try adding this `--disable-web-security`

Comment: I´m not developing this extension for myself and I can´t ask people who wants to use it to do this.

Comment: are you using [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)?

Comment: no, I´m using [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). You should also read this **While JSONP supports only the GET request method, CORS also supports other types of HTTP requests.** I need to get data to server not from server.

Comment: pretty strange thing is that it works now, I´m not aware of any change in either server or client side that would cause this. It happened after chrome update to version 28, but I´m pretty sure it wasn´t working for a while in version 28.

Comment: @hynner Your page may have suddenly started working due to a caching problem, e.g., a broken version of your code was cached somewhere, and once the cache cleared/updated, your corrected code finally went into effect.

Comment: @apsillers yeah it´s possible, I guess I´ll never find it out ;-) Anyway it didn´t work in chrome 27, so I guess that it was chrome bug which got repaired.

Comment: Neither answer really helped, so I can´t accept any.

Comment: I also got this problem, I suspect it's a bug with the CORS add-on that I use.

Answer (score 15):

I face a similar problem in `node.js` with CORS

You need to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the specific domain not a wildcard.

Example: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `http://website.com`

> (You can have on your server an array of origins allowed and check
>   against the request if it is allowed then answer with that one instead
>   of wildcards.)

Also, you can set the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers to a list of options like:

```
POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
```

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I tried setting it to the same value as Origin header with no luck. According to specification wildcards should be allowed. Setting Access-Control-Allow-Methods to multiple values didn´t help either.

Comment: why they force such an action ?

Answer (score 11):

you should allow OPTIONS in your response header..

"Access-Control-Allow-Methods ", "GET, POST,HEAD, OPTIONS,PUT, DELETE"

Comment: I have it allowed now, but it doesn´t help anyway.

Comment: and also allow for PATCH as same ... i think you already added this

Comment: yeah PATCH is allowed, read my comment on the main question, it works now, but I´m not sure why :-)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I stumbled on the same problem. The thing that solved the issue for me was uninstalling the extension I had in chrome for allowing cors before I set up cors on the backend. The extenstion can be found here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en. So make sure you dont have any extensions in chrome that could mess this up.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the CORS on Chrome 27.0.1453.116 and it worked for me.
From the client side all i did is in jquery AJAX set the '**crossDomain**' to **true**.

```
$.ajax('http://localhost/Elements.Services/Elements.svc/REST/Element/Get?ID=1', {
                    type: 'GET',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                      alert(data);
                    }
                });
```

While on REST service side for each request set the following response headers:

1. ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept") 
   or 
   ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", HTTPRequest.RequestedHeaders + "Accept")
2. ("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,PUT,GET")
3. ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

[**Here**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) is Great article on CORS working, which really helped me.

Comment: As I said in the question, GET worked fine for me too, but other requests were causing a problem.

Comment: I tried with POST as well and it works fine, though not with PUT/DELETE.

Comment: Have you tried adding custom headers? It´s hard to say, I´m not saying it shouldn´t work, because it should. I´m just saying it didn´t work for me and now it works.

Comment: Thats fine. If it's working now. Its good. Sometime we get this really weird issues which are hard to reproduce/understand. (Not using any custom headers)

Answer (score 0):

In your WebApi:

**Add** the **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors** NuGet package to the project

Make sure you also **register CORS support** either Globally, at the Controller, or at the Action.

***Global -***
In your **WebApiConfig.cs** file from **App_Start** folder add:

`public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{`

`// New code:
   var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
      origins: "*",
      headers: "*", 
      methods: "*");
   config.EnableCors(cors);`

`// Other configurations`

`}`

***Controller*** or ***Action -*** If desired/required to place support at these levels (*this will overwrite global settings* - Action > Controller > Config). Above Controller or Action signature:

`[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:[*port #*]", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`

**Note:** * are "wildcards", might want to put the domain making the request **ex:**(http://localhost:[*port #*])

Something that is very easy to miss/forget...

IN solution explorer, right-click api-project. In properties window **set 'Anonymous Authentication' to Enabled !!!**

Answer (score -3):

why not just use `PUT` instead of `PATCH` and your request type. They pretty much do the same thing

Comment: Because that is the wrong verb, they do not do the same thing. PATCH is for changing properties on something, PUT is for replacing an entire object.