# Missing Patch method with corsheaders only on chrome

Tags: reactjs, django, google-chrome, http-headers, cors

I have a Django app that's using `corsheaders` package and its in settings.py like this:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [ ..., corsheaders, ...]
...
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # on top
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    ...
]
...
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

When I'm trying to do a `PATCH` request on Google Chrome after the `OPTIONS` method I get this:

[image: Google Chrome PATCH request]

The Access-Control-Allow-Methods is missing `PATCH`and the next request fails with CORS methods error.

But I tried the same method on Firefox and its working as intended.

[image: Firefox PATCH request]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need to **set allowed origins explicitly**, not by using the wildcard i.e. `*`:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://example.com",
    "https://sub.example.com",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:9000"
]
```

Also, set all HTTP verbs:

```
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]
```

Read more:

- https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/
- [Chrome Cross-Domain PATCH request not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17468774/2873538)
- `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True` or `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` (OLD name) is equal to using wildcard `*` : [L131 django-cors-headers middleware.py file](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers/blob/5b2368749e4e8650e7a88fc174ee78598f8fc0b9/src/corsheaders/middleware.py#L131)

Comment: Yea I have added this and its still not working for chrome, I even tested chromium and it works on it...